# Do all languages with pre-positional articles have zero-articles if they don't have post-positional articles?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, romance-languages, germanic-languages, slavic-languages

To clarify, *pre-positional* articles are the articles positioned *before* a noun they refer to, like English *the* or *a(n)*.

*Post-positional* articles are those positioned *after* a noun they refer to, like Swedish *-en/-ett*, or *-na* in ***en skog => skogen*** (forest => the forest), ***ett barn =>barnet*** (a child => the child),  Romanian *-l/-le* in ***codru => codrul*** (forest => the forest), or Bulgarian *-ът /-та / -то / -те*, e.g. ***гора = гората*** (forest => the forest), etc.

If we look at the languages which have *pre-positional* articles (not to be confused with languages with articles merged into prepositions, like French *du*, or Italian *della*) but which have no *post-positional* articles, then we notice that these languages also have *zero articles*.

In [English, the zero articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_article_in_English#Zero_article) are used with mass noun singular.

In French, the zero article (or [article zéro](http://books.google.ru/books/about/L_Article_Z%C3%A9ro_en_Fran%C3%A7ais_Contemporai.html?id=lskaSr4WCFQC&redir_esc=y)) serves to denote 'neither massive nor countable' non-partitive noun (which, to my understanding, is somewhat similar to that of Sumerian types of plural).

In Spanish, the zero article (or [artículo cero](http://www.um.es/lincoing/jv/2002%20Contrastivo%20Carabela.pdf)) stands for non-possessivness (?) and group partitive.

Dutch also has zero articles, although it is difficult to find any reliable work on this topic.

What is the situation with *prepositional* zero articles in other languages?

Comment: Once again, this is not at all clear. Articles do not modify prepositions; so what could "_prepositional_ zero articles" possibly mean? In any language?

Comment: First, I think you mean *bare prepositional phrases*. I've been doing some research on this, so let me tell you a couple of things: 1. You'll find a lot more literature under the label 'bare nominals'. 2. There's **plenty of reliable work** on this topic for Dutch. It would be good for you to look for *Kale Naamwoorden* or just Dutch bare nominals. You'll find a lot of sources. 3. As for bare PPs, you could start with [this](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/detless-pp.final.pdf) and [this](http://www.llf.cnrs.fr/Gens/Mardale/le.bruyn_de.swart_zwarts.pdf).

Comment: There's also the usage _intransitive prepositions_, which is a common way to look at the "particle" in phrasal verbs, along with various adverbial uses.

Comment: From the title I assumed that "prepositional articles" meant contractions of a preposition and an article, like _du_ in French, _am_ in German and _no_ in Portuguese; but the question doesn't seem to refer to them. I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: Definite articles come after the noun in some cases in Scandinavian languages, but mass nouns can still appear without an article. Not sure about Romanian and Bulgarian, but I don't see why the two phenomena should be correlated. As for your question, can you make it more specific than "What is the situation"? Not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: The question is about prepositional zero articles in languages which have no postpositional articles. Usage, implications, grammatical rules, examples, etc. Anything.

Comment: @Manjusri: Yes, that's what you said before. But you still haven't told us what **you** think "prepositional zero articles" means. It doesn't mean anything to me, so I can't help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, there are languages with prepositional articles only (e.g. Hungarian, English, French, Spanish, Dutch and German). There are languages with post-positional articles only (e.g. Basque and Bulgarian, and here my list ends up). There also languages with both pre-positional and post-positional articles (Swedish, Danish and Romanian). Of all the languages, some tongues having prepositional articles also have post-positional ones, and others don't. So let's consider the group mentioned in the title.

Comment: So, what you're looking for is a correlation between "prepositional articles" and "zero articles". Is that it?

Comment: Not quite. E.g. we cannot say that Basque has 'prepositional zero articles', or 'prepositional articles', because it has no prepositional articles at all. So the question is about languages with prepositional articles only: do they also (and obligatory) have zero prepositional articles (= meaningful absence of prepositional article)?